# Fluent UI (Ribbon): Is it possible to target multiple tabs?

Tags: vsto, ribbon, office-2007

I have a custom "help" button which I would like to appear on several tabs:  TabNewMailMessage, TabMail (a.k.a Home), TabReadMessage.  I can accomplish this by creating several tab elementes in the ribbon XML file but this doesn't seem very DRY.  Is it possible to define the button once and have it target several tabs?

```
<tab idMso="TabMail">
    <group id="g_Home" label="Support">
      <button id="btCreateHelpEmail_Home" label="Help" size="large" imageMso="QuickSearchOrganizer" onAction="CreateHelpEmail"  />
    </group>
</tab>
<tab idMso="TabReadMessage">
    <group id="g_ReadMessage" label="Support">
      <button id="btCreateHelpEmail_ReadMessage" label="Help" size="large" imageMso="QuickSearchOrganizer" onAction="CreateHelpEmail"  />
    </group>
</tab>
<tab idMso="TabNewMailMessage">
    <group id="g_NewMail" label="Support">
      <button id="btCreateHelpEmail_NewMail" label="Help" size="large" imageMso="QuickSearchOrganizer" onAction="CreateHelpEmail"  />
    </group>
</tab>
```